# Is shape-rendering possible for div figures?

Tags: javascript

I'm drawing a rhombus and its edges look like pixels.

```css
.rhombus {
  --g: var(--c, white) calc(49.5% - 3px), #000 calc(49.5% - 2px), #000 49.5%, transparent 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, var(--g)) top right, linear-gradient(to top left, var(--g)) top left, linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--g)) bottom right, linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--g)) bottom left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 700px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="rhombus"></div>
```

[image]

Is it possible to smooth the edges of the figure?
PS: pure JS/CSS

Comment: It is rendered with a smooth edge in both Chrome and Firefox (on macOS). What browser are you using?

Comment: the edges look smooth to me (https://i.imgur.com/EWi8L1H.png) Maybe the hardware acceleration settings in your browser are wonky. A hack I've used to force hardware acceleration is to apply a nonvisible rotation to the element, like `transform: rotate(0.1deg);` may work in some browsers. or just adjust your settings in your browser

Comment: @evolutionxbox Chrome. It looks good when scaling, but looks like pixels at 100% scale